# Using Model in Scriban template

Tags: sxa, scriban

Is it possible to use the current Model in Scriban?

I have a CutomHeroViewModel

```
public class CustomHeroViewModel : VariantsRenderingModel
{
    public string HeroTitle { get; set; }
    public string HeroDescription { get; set; }
    public List<string> ImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to use its properties in a Scriban template.

I tried the following code **{{ o_model.HeroTitle }}** but its showing empty value

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Keep in mind that Scriban by default is lower casing properties and using underscore to separate the words. So property called `VariantFields` will be accessible in Scriban by `variant_fields`. Take a look here:

[image]

Please refer to the Scriban documentation for more details: https://github.com/lunet-io/scriban

> By default, Properties and methods of .NET objects are automatically
> exposed with lowercase and _ names. It means that a property like
> MyMethodIsNice will be exposed as my_method_is_nice. This is the
> default convention, originally to match the behavior of liquid
> templates. If you want to change this behavior, you need to use a
> MemberRenamer delegate.